# jQuery .removeData() not working as expeted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone explain this jQuery behaviour. I have `data-hello` attribute, when I call `.removeData('hello')` I expect it to not affect anything, since the attribute is still there, and the next `.data()` call should simply re-retrieve the value from that `data-hello` attribute. Why then it's not doing that in the following code.

```js
console.log($('.outer').data())

//removing jquery data (should only remove jquery cache?)
$('.outer').removeData('hello')

// attribute is still there but .data() call not getting it
console.log($('.outer').data())
console.log($('.outer').attr('data-hello'))
```

```html
<div class="outer" data-hello=1 >hello</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Docs describing expected behaviour https://api.jquery.com/removeData/

> Note that .removeData() will only remove data from jQuery's internal
>   .data() cache, and any corresponding data- attributes on the element
>   will not be removed. A later call to data() will therefore re-retrieve
>   the value from the data- attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because jQuery's `data()` returns the internal cache. Since you have removed the key `hello`, then `data()` should not see the `hello` again.

If you read the key `hello` again, then it comes into the data internal cache, then `data()` can see it again.

See the demo below:

```js
console.log('init data(): ' + JSON.stringify($('.outer').data()))

//removing jquery data key from jquery data cache
$('.outer').removeData('hello')

// attribute is still there, .data() call not getting it
console.log('removed data(): ' + JSON.stringify($('.outer').data()))

// read the key again, it comes from the html attribute to the cache
console.log('call data(hello): ' + JSON.stringify($('.outer').data('hello')))

// then the data() can see the key
console.log('then data(): ' + JSON.stringify($('.outer').data()))

console.log($('.outer').attr('data-hello'))
```

```html
<div class="outer" data-hello=1 >hello</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```